# My custom Simio user extension does not get picked up

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have created my custom UserExtension for Simio in C#. I have used one of their examples and changed a few thing just to try this functionality. 
Unfortunately when I deploy it in the specific folder listed in their Reference guide the software never picks it up and I cannot use my extenstions.

At first I thought I did not follow some naming convention. But the I have tried opening one of their projects and simply change the description, then build it and replac the dll. It did not pick it up again. So I come to the conclusion that there is some incompatibility between my Visual Studio settings - I have VS 2013, and the Simio software. I have tried launching both the 32bit and 64bit versions of Simio - no difference.

I have registered in the Simio forums, but they are very restrictive and I cannot just ask a question there, I have to wait for permission...

I will be very grateful If someone has any clues what might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build traget from DEBUG to PRODUCTION or similar. I had the same issue and this helped resolve it.

Also be sure that the folder within the `/UserExtensions` folder has the same name as your DLL file. Example:

DLL: `MyOwnStep.dll`
Put in folder: `/UserExtensions/MyOwnStep/`

To build in DEBUG mode should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem recently.
After some research I found out that Simio comes in different versions.

One limitation is that the license-free Simio Personal Edition does not allow addins to be activated by the user. Therefore, a license is required for use. (Which is strange, because some UserExtenions are already provided by SimIo and can be used).